# Style vs. ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, styles, controltemplate

is it possible to define resources in the style rather then using a template?

```
    <ListView.Resources >
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
         </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
```

How can I wrap this thing into:

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}"> 

   </Style>
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly... is that what you're looking for ?

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
          <Style.Resources>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}"> 

              </Style>

          </Style.Resources>
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
     </Style>
```